# Could not find or load main class com.liferay.portal.tools.SassToCssBuilder

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, liferay, liferay-6

I'm using Liferay 6.2 CE. When I'm deploying my portlet, this error message is shown.

```
Buildfile: /home/matej/liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2/portlets/RegistrationForm-portlet/build.xml
war:
     [java] Error: Could not find or load main class com.liferay.portal.tools.SassToCssBuilder

BUILD FAILED
/home/matej/liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2/build-common.xml:2468: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/matej/liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2/build-common.xml:2473: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/matej/liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2/build-common.xml:322: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/matej/liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2/build-common.xml:2104: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/matej/liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2/build-common.xml:175: Java returned: 1

Total time: 5 seconds
```

Yesterday everything worked just fine... I finished my work saved progress and closed eclipse. Today, after opening eclipse with my project this error message is shown. I'm using liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2, so don't know where the problem is. I will appreciate any kind of help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read [here](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/12239498). Same problem.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, however as David wrote in the topic is that "The reason you're getting it is you're using the 6.1 SDK trying to build your portlet for a 6.0 portal." But I'm using 6.2 SDK on 6.2 portal, that's the reason why it worked, until now o.O .

Comment: Did the portlet you created defined to be built and run on a liferay portal with SDK 6.2?

Comment: Yes of course, I downloaded and switched to a fresh SDK plugins, the same problem, it's just mad today...

Comment: So I used fresh bundle, SDK also eclipse, working well... Leaving it here for further use.

Comment: How did you solve it in the end @MatejŠípka? I am facing the same problem with a fresh 6.2 GA6 bundle.